# PCL Estimate normals at sharp corners give curved result

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have used PCL to estimate normals in a point cloud from a known correct viewpoint

```
float radius 0.1;    
pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr tree (new  pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
tree->setInputCloud(in);
pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::Normal> n;
n.setInputCloud (in);
n.setSearchMethod (tree);
n.setRadiusSearch (radius);
n.setViewPoint(vx, vy, vz); // Known correct viewpoint
n.compute (*out);
```

This works well for most of the time but when there are sharp corners (e.g. something box shaped) the normals on and in proximity of the corner become wrongly angled to the surface. See below where the wrongly angled normals easily can be seen in blue (snapshot from Meshlab) and the point cloud without normals can been seen below.

[image: Normals shown in blue]
[image]

According to this tutorial http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/normal_estimation.php the search area is important and one can lower it to get finer and finer details. But if a lower it and lower it not much changes for and  eventually I get below the density of the cloud and then all normals are pointing more less in the wrong direction. The latter is understandable as the plane that is used to estimate becomes far to small.

What can I do to get less of wrongly angled normals on the corners and also hopefully keep them angled on surfaces that are actually curved?

These curved normals latter create problems in segmentation that the top of the desk and the side are not connected and there is a large gap.

Ultimately I want to solve the gap in the meshing and it is my belief that it is the wrongly angled normals on the corners that are at fault for this.

**Update: I managed to get the normals to be resonable by doubling the density of my point cloud, the density was simply to low for finding the plane even with double the radius for the search.**

[image: mesh with gaps]

Comment: What do you mean with "wrongly angled" normals? Are they pointing in the wrong direction? Or do you want the normals to be perfectly angled, e.g. jumping from `0°` to `90°`?

Comment: Yes too many point in the wrong direction around the corners. To get them perfectly aligned 0° to 90° would be awesome but I don't think it is needed or easily achieved?

Comment: You can also compute normals with [Moving Least Squares](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_moving_least_squares.html) by setting `setComputeNormals` to `true`, `setPolynomialFit` to `true` and `setPolynomialOrder` to `2`.  With the `polynomial fit` you can get better results at edges.